# Use VirtualBox to compile iPhone app (via PhoneGap or Titanium) on Windows 7 machine?

Tags: iphone, ios4, cordova, titanium, virtualbox

Is it possible to use VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org) to compile an iPhone app on a Windows 7 machine?

Specifically, we would like to utilize PhoneGap (http://www.phonegap.com) or Titanium (http://www.appcelerator.com/) to build the iPhone app.

PhoneGap requires Mac OS X Snow Leopard, which we would install on an instance of VirtualBox.

Has anyone done this before?

Yes, we understand this violates Apple's ToS. This is a prototype.

Comment: Oops I answered it. This "answer" deserves a comment- "I have done it before and in Apple's own words: It just works. :)" Answer deleted.

Comment: Why didn't you answer? Then we can credit you. Did you have any problems installing VirtualBox or Snow Leopard or using PhoneGap?

Comment: Can't vouch for PhoneGap. But I've done titanium. And in fact before I purchased my macbook pro I was running Xcode and iOS simulator on my OS X copy on virtual box. It worked. And after that I installed OS X on my PC (hackintosh). Now I run it on my MBP though. I removed the answer because it was just a simple yes. You may up vote my comments though :)

Comment: Well, how about if I change the question to ask about hurdles you encountered? From a dev perspective, what is the difference between Hackintosh and installing OSX on Virtual Box on Windows 7? Our goal is to bundle a HTML5 web app into a native app shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend looking into PhoneGap Build https://build.phonegap.com/

PhoneGap Build allows you to upload your source to their build service and get back app-store ready packages for a variety of platforms.

As far as I can tell, the only thing you need a Mac for in this process is to set up your provisioning profiles and developer certificate.  Then you upload those to PhoneGap's service. From there it seems you should be able to use a non-Apple computer to develop and upload to the service.

Comment: What about running an emulator?  I have an PhoneGap Android app... I still need to test it after I compile an iOS version.

Comment: You can test on an iOS device. If you don't have one of those either, then yeah, you have a testing issue. It's not an ideal solution, I admit.